# Is computing subgradients an open research area in Authomatic Differentiation

Tags: mathematical-programming, mathematical-analysis

Large portions of the possible research areas in Automatic Differentiation have broadly defined known solutions; most of which were derived in the 80s and 90s.
Compute vector jacobian products: use reverse mode.
Compute jacobian vector products: use forwards mode.
(other things are a bit less solved, but still, we have a solid idea of what the solution space is e.g. computing whole jacobians using mixed-mode, and  computing single partial derivatives using cross-country)
There is a lot of work and refinements and tweaks to those ideas that are still active research today,
and also a lot of implementations and innovations there.
But the core of the ideas is well-established.

Is this also the case for automatically computing [subgradients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subderivative)?
Is current work variations on existing ideas,
or is current work proposing whole new ideas?